# Jquery calendar clickable dropdown events

Tags: jquery, events, calendar

I have a query to show calendar events in jquery calendar. i want to pop out all the year events on mouse over and clicking on events i want to show a separate browser window to show the details of event. all events comes dynamically. please help me???

this is my link

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4s7nU/23/)

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var Event = function (text, className) {
        this.text = text;
        this.className = className;
    };

    var events = {};
    events[new Date("09/14/2013")] = new Event("Valentines Day", "green");

    events[new Date("09/18/2013")] = new Event("Payday", "green");

    console.dir(events);

    $("#dates").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            var event = events[date];
            if (event) {
                return [true, event.className, event.text];
            } else {
                return [true, '', ''];
            }
        }
    });



    $(document.body).on('mouseenter', '.green', function () {
        //  alert(1);
        var $myval = $(this).attr('title');
        //alert($myval);
        $(this).append('<div class="dyn"><a href="google.com" target="_blank" ></a><span  >cancel</span></div>');


        $('.dyn a').html($myval);
        //$('.pop').show();

    });
    //);


    $(document.body).on('mouseleave', '.green', function () {

        $(this).children('a').next('div').remove();

        return true;
    });



    $('.pop a').live('click', function () {
        var $mixtc = $('.pop a').val();
        alert($mixtc);
        $(this).parent().remove();

    });
});
```

Comment: I didn't understand what's your budget and when are you going to pay

Comment: please include more code.

Comment: i have comeup with the result. its just i want to add more event on same date. for example 12th september two events? is it possible